# For ideals $J$ and $K$, if $J \cap K = {0}$, then $jk=0$ for every $j \in J$ and $k \in K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $A$ be a ring, and let $J$ and $K$ be ideals of $A$.

Prove that if $J \cap K = {0}$, then $jk=0$ for every $j \in J$ and $k \in K$.

Attempt: I just can't seem to see where to start in this problem.

We know that $J$ ideal $\implies ja, aj \in J$; and $K$ ideal $\implies ka, ak \in K$ for any $a \in A$. So we have, for instance, $(aj)(ka) \in A \implies a(jk)a \in A$ which implies $jk \in A$.

But this doesn't tell us anything apart from the very obvious... I just can't seem to find a way to the $jk = 0$ bit...

Any help/ideas would be great, thanks.

Comment: Apparently the reason that this is not obvious is the inability to decode "for all" statements.

Comment: Note that $JK\subset J\cap K$ for any two ideals $J,K$;You have done it just arrange the implications together

Comment: @KennyLau Thanks for the condescending remarks, and have a nice Christmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $J$ is an ideal in $A$,

$j \in J \Longrightarrow jk \in J; \tag 1$

since $K$ is an ideal in $A$,

$k \in K \Longrightarrow jk \in K; \tag 2$

thus

$jk \in J \cap K = \{0\}; \tag 3$

(3) evidently forces

$jk = 0, \; \forall j \in J,\; \forall k \in K. \tag 4$

I have assumed in the above that $J$ and $K$ are two-sided ideals; however, it is easy to see that the result follows provided $J$ is a right, and $K$ a left, ideal in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

So we have $jk\in J$ and $jk\in K$...